# How I can take value of radio in Flask when on html i have a name of radio what changed on loop

Tags: python, html, database, loops, flask

There is code of html

```
{% for row in quest %}
            <div class="cntrn wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"><h9>{{ row["Question"] }}</h9></div>
            <br> <br>
            {% for answ in anw %}
            {% if row["Questions_id"] == answ["Questions_id"] %}
            <form method="post" action="/test1">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ row['Questions_id'] }}" id="flexRadioDefault1" value="{{ answ['answer'] }}">
                    <div class="cntrn wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"><h10><label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                    {{ answ["answer"] }}
                    </label></h10></div>
                </div>
                <br>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
                <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg green" type="submit">Check</button>
            </form>
```

And there app.py code

```
if request.method == "POST":
    user_id = session["User_id"]
    Test_id = 1
    quest = db.execute("SELECT Questions.Questions_id, Question, Ranswer FROM Questions WHERE Test_id = ?", Test_id)
    for r in range(len(quest)):
        if request.form['name of radio'] != 0:
            q_id = quest[r]["Questions_id"]
            answr = request.form['name of radio']
            if not answr:
                flash("Give answers for all questions")
                return redirect('/test1')
            elif answr == quest[r]["Question"]:
                ransw = quest[r]["Ranswer"]
                if answr == ransw:
                    count = count + 1
                db.execute("INSERT INTO Progress (User_id, Test_id) VALUES (?, ?)", user_id, Test_id)
    return render_template('subtest.html', count=count)
```

How I can compare value of radio, what was selected by user, and value of right answer on DataBase?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a solution

```
@app.route('/test1', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test1():
    count = 0
    if request.method == "GET":
        Test_id = 1
        quest = db.execute("SELECT Questions.Questions_id, Question, Ranswer FROM Questions WHERE Test_id = ?", Test_id)
        anw = db.execute("SELECT Answers.Answer as 'answer', Questions_id FROM Questions JOIN Answers ON Answers.Question_id=Questions.Questions_id WHERE Questions_id IN (SELECT Answers.Answ_id FROM Answers WHERE Test_id = ?)", Test_id)
        return render_template("test1.html", quest=quest, anw=anw)
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = session["User_id"]
        Test_id = 1
        quest = db.execute("SELECT Questions.Questions_id, Question, Ranswer FROM Questions WHERE Test_id = ?", Test_id)
        for r in range(len(quest)):
            for row in quest:
                q_id = quest[r]["Questions_id"]
                answr = request.form[row['Question']]
                if not answr:
                    flash("Please, give answers on all of the questions")
                    return redirect('/test1')
                else:
                    ransw = quest[r]["Ranswer"]
                    if answr == ransw:
                        count = count + 1
        if count > 1:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO Progress (User_id, Test_id) VALUES (?, ?)", user_id, Test_id)
        return render_template('subtest.html', count=count)
```

If you want to check for user select something, you must add `required` on the `<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ row['Question'] }}" id="flexRadioDefault1" value="{{ answ['answer'] }}" required>`
Code, which I use before on Fllask for checking it - doesn't work